# How to check HTML5 Video Time Update before and after?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm trying to check the current playback time changed of the video in HTML5. I'm currently using the `seeking` event to check the current playback time changed. But I want to know to what duration is the time changed to and where was the time before hand.

If someone can't understand the question properly, comment below.

My code:

```html
<html>
<body>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<p>Playback position NOW: <span id="pos1"></span> | This should show the duration the video is at after 'seeking' event</p>
<p>Playback position BEFORE: <span id="pos2"></span> | This should show the duration the video was at after 'seeking' event</p>

<script>
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  vid.addEventListener("seeking", function(){before(vid.currentTime);});
  vid.addEventListener('seeked', after);

  function before(time)
  {
     document.getElementById("pos1").innerHTML = time;
  }
  function after()
  {
     document.getElementById("pos2").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at both the [`seeking`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/seeking) and [`seeked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/seeked) events. Perhaps by finding the `currentTime` when you begin seeking and then finding it again when `seeked` is fired, you can output those two.

Comment: I have changed my code. My new code doens't work. Thats all I could think of.

Comment: You changed this to pass the result of the function into the addEventListener. What you want is something like `vid.addEventLIstener("seeking", function(){ before(vid.currentTime); }` -- this way, you're still passing the reference to a function. You could probably just write it exactly like your before.

Comment: I tried your given method but I receive the same time for before and after.... I have updated my code again.